# hibernate one-to-many without DB relation mapping

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

Will my code work if I apply one-to-many relation in hibernate-
**only to entities side in Java and not to DB side** (there will not be foreign key between tables and I don't want to modify tables) ?

Question edited below.

Here are my tables - One employee has many certificates

Emp table -->

```
   id (Primary key)

   first_name

   last_name

   salary

   emp_id
```

Certificates Table -->

```
   id (primary key)

   certificate_name 

   cert_id
```

Here , these tables data are related with `emp_id` and `cert_id`.(There is no relation in tables for this. But looking at data in existing system they are related)

As it is an existing DB , I don't want to change tables and add foreign key relation in DB.
And I want to add relation from hibernate side only. Is it possible. ?

Comment: Please, add your entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to the `id` field only instead of the entity in your certificates entity. Your employee entity will remain the same but without the `@OneToMany` relation. In your certificate entity instead of doing:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
Employee employee
```

Do it like:

```
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
Integer employeeId;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Hibernate does not need a ForeignKey relation on the Database side.
If you have hbm2ddl turned off, hibernate will not create one.

Just declare it as a normal one-to-many relation and hibernate will make a collection of certs for an employee. Be sure to use Set or Bag not List since List needs an index column.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary keys are the same, this is officially and purely a **one-to-one** relation which can be mapped as such. There is nothing you need additionally in the database.